# Having an issue with reading a file and having it spam console with no sleep avail

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log('Line from file:', line);
});
```

Okay, so I got that code from another source here. But the issue is whenever I attempt to do a timeout or anything it just will all spam at once Im really struggling here and would really love some help with this one. Also sorry I screwed up and forgot to add what im attempting to do is run the command only when the line is in the console and has been there for a certain period of time 15 seconds for instance.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "it just will all spam at once"? I'm assuming you're not asking about running a spam server or something equally nefarious. Note that you can [edit] your question, so you don't need text like "Also sorry I screwed up" :).

Comment: Oh okay thanks sorry new to this. Also, no Im not attempting to spam anything haha. Here is basically the issue. I attempt to do any sort of delay before re-running the command that I am doing where on the post it's console.log line from file and it does nothing after ONE delay. Example: 
`var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input : fs.createReadStream('accounts.txt'),
      output: process.stdout,
      terminal: false
})
rl.on('line',function(line){
     for (i in line){
 sleep(2000).then(() => {
        console.log('woot');
    });
}
})` just fills my console with woot